# How can I access the web GUI for the Trendnet TEG-160WS smart switch?

Tags: switch

The management utility reports the switch at 192.168.0.1 but I get an error going to that IP in the browser and if I try to change the IP or enable DHCP in the utility the change is rejected. Windows peer-to-peer LAN.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: "Google Chrome could not connect to 192.168.0.1"

Comment: whats the output of 'ipconfig /all' ? you may need to set your PC to use a static IP like 192.168.0.45, and then once you have the switch configured, you can switch back to using DHCP.

Comment: I was on DHCP but tried switching to static per your advice - no help. I'm not directly connected to the smart switch but could not access it from a CPU this is directly connected.

Comment: is your pc usually in the 192.168.0.0/24 network? for the terminal directly connected to the switch, is it in the 192.168.0 network? if not put the terminal in that network in order to connect. then once your connected, change the switches ip so it is in your normal network, and switch the terminal back to dhcp.